# Parent seems to be lost after drag and drop

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to implement a drag and drop soultion in qml without using models and delegates.  So I create four containers and four rectangles with diferent colors and I want to move the rectangles dragging them and when one rectangle is dropped on another one i need to exchange the positions.

So far i've managed to acomplise that using reparenting but the second time I try to move another rectangle (or the same one it complains about cannot anchor to a null Item (as if the parent were destroyed or something

It has to be another easier way to drag and drop whitout using lists or models...  I would apreciate any insight about this.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow{
    id:root
    minimumWidth: 1024
    minimumHeight: 700
    visible: true
    title: "PlannerX2"
    Component.onCompleted: {
        root.showMaximized();

    }

    property int toIndex: -1
    property int fromIndex: -1
    property string sobreEscrito:""
    property var  posiciones: ["rojo","verde","azul","naranja"]
    property var  contenedores: ["vtk2dSceneAxialHolder","vtk2dSceneSagitalHolder","vtk2dSceneCoronalHolder","vtk3dSceneHolder"]
    function returnFather( i)
    {
        switch (contenedores[i])
        {
        case "vtk2dSceneAxialHolder":
            return vtk2dSceneAxialHolder

        case   "vtk2dSceneSagitalHolder":
            return vtk2dSceneSagitalHolder

        case  "vtk2dSceneCoronalHolder":
            return vtk2dSceneCoronalHolder

        case "vtk3dSceneHolder":
            return vtk3dSceneHolder

        }
    }


    Rectangle {
        id: screenCanvasUI
        anchors.fill: parent




        //        Frame {
        //            id: view2dFrame
        //            visible: true
        //            rightPadding:  0
        //            leftPadding: 0
        //            topPadding: 0
        //            bottomPadding: 0
        //            width: parent.width/3
        //            anchors.left: parent.left
        //            anchors.top: parent.top
        //            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom



        Rectangle{
            id: vtk2dSceneAxialHolder
            property int minHeight
            height: parent.height/3
            Layout.minimumHeight: minHeight
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.left: parent.left
           width: parent.width/3


            DropArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onEntered: {
                    console.log("entrando en area Axial")
                    toIndex=0

                }
                onExited: {
                    console.log("saliendo de area Axial")
                    toIndex=-1
                }
            }
            Rectangle{
                id:rojo
                color: "red"
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                Drag.active: rojoMouseArea.drag.active
                Drag.hotSpot.x: rojo.width/2
                Drag.hotSpot.y: rojo.height/2
                property bool update:false

                states:[
                    State{
                        name: "moving"
                        when: (rojo.Drag.active && verde.Drag.active===false && azul.Drag.active===false&& naranja.Drag.active===false)
                        ParentChange{
                            target: rojo
                            parent: screenCanvasUI
                        }
                        AnchorChanges{
                            target:rojo
                            anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined
                            anchors.verticalCenter: undefined
                            anchors.left: undefined
                            anchors.right: undefined
                            anchors.bottom: undefined
                            anchors.top: undefined

                        }
                        PropertyChanges {
                            target: rojo
                            width: 200
                            height:200
                            anchors.left: undefined
                            anchors.top: undefined
                        }
                    },
                    State{
                        name: "dropping"
                        when: (toIndex!==-1 && rojo.Drag.active===false && verde.Drag.active===false && azul.Drag.active===false&& naranja.Drag.active===false && toIndex!==-1  )
                        ParentChange{
                            target: rojo
                            parent:returnFather(posiciones.indexOf("rojo"))

                        }
                        PropertyChanges {
                            target: rojo
                            width: parent.width
                            height:parent.height
                            anchors.left: parent.left
                            anchors.top: parent.top
                        }
                    }

                ]
                Item{
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    width: 20
                    height: 20
                    Frame{
                        anchors.fill:parent
                    }

                    MouseArea{

                        id:rojoMouseArea
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        drag.target: rojo
                        onClicked:
                        {
                            toIndex=-1
                            fromIndex=-1
                            console.log(screenCanvasUI)
                            console.log(toIndex)
                            console.log(fromIndex)
                            console.log(rojoMouseArea.drag.active)

                        }

                        drag.onActiveChanged: {
                            if (rojoMouseArea.drag.active)
                            {
                                console.log(toIndex)
                                console.log(fromIndex)

                                toIndex=-1
                                rojo.update=false
                                azul.update=false
                                verde.update=false
                                naranja.update=false
                                fromIndex=posiciones.indexOf("rojo");
                                console.log(toIndex)
                                console.log(fromIndex)


                            }
                            else{

                                var temp= posiciones[fromIndex];
                                posiciones[fromIndex]=posiciones[toIndex]
                                posiciones[toIndex]=temp;
                                rojo.Drag.drop()

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Rectangle{
            id: vtk2dSceneSagitalHolder
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top :vtk2dSceneAxialHolder.bottom
            height: parent.height/3
            width: parent.width/3

            DropArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onEntered: {
                    console.log("entrando en area Sagital")
                    toIndex=1
                }
                onExited: {
                    console.log("saliendo de area Sagital")

                    toIndex=-1
                }
            }
            Rectangle{
                id:verde
                color: "green"
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                property bool update:false
                Drag.active: verdeMouseArea.drag.active
                Drag.hotSpot.x: verde.width/2
                Drag.hotSpot.y: verde.height/2
                states:[
                    State{
                        name: "moving"
                        when: (verde.Drag.active && rojo.Drag.active===false && azul.Drag.active===false && naranja.Drag.active===false)
                        ParentChange{
                            target: verde
                            parent: screenCanvasUI

                        }
                        AnchorChanges{
                            target:verde
                            anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined
                            anchors.verticalCenter: undefined
                            anchors.left: undefined
                            anchors.right: undefined
                            anchors.bottom: undefined
                            anchors.top: undefined
                        }
                        PropertyChanges {
                            target: verde
                            width: 200
                            height:200
                            anchors.left: undefined
                            anchors.top: undefined
                        }
                    },
                    State{
                        name: "dropping"
                        when: ( toIndex!==-1 && verde.Drag.active===false && rojo.Drag.active===false && azul.Drag.active===false && naranja.Drag.active===false)
                        ParentChange{
                            target: verde
                            parent:returnFather(posiciones.indexOf("verde"))//{contenedores[toIndex]}

                        }
                        PropertyChanges {
                            target: verde
                            width: parent.width
                            height:parent.height
                            anchors.left: parent.left
                            anchors.top: parent.top

                        }
                    }

                ]
                Item{
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    width: 20
                    height: 20
                    Frame{
                        anchors.fill:parent
                    }
                    MouseArea{
                        id:verdeMouseArea
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        drag.target: verde
                        drag.onActiveChanged: {
                            if (verdeMouseArea.drag.active)
                            {
                                toIndex=-1
                                fromIndex=posiciones.indexOf("verde");
                                rojo.update=false
                                azul.update=false
                                verde.update=false
                                naranja.update=false
                            }
                            else{

                                var temp= posiciones[fromIndex];
                                posiciones[fromIndex]=posiciones[toIndex]
                                posiciones[toIndex]=temp;
                                verde.Drag.drop();


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Rectangle{
            id: vtk2dSceneCoronalHolder
            height: parent.height/3
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            width: parent.width/3

            DropArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onEntered: {
                    console.log("entrando en area Coronal")
                    toIndex=2
                }
                onExited: {
                    console.log("saliendo de area Coronal")

                    toIndex=-1
                }
            }
            Rectangle{
                id:azul
                color: "blue"
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height
                property bool update:false
                Drag.active: azulMouseArea.drag.active
                Drag.hotSpot.x: azul.width/2
                Drag.hotSpot.y: azul.height/2
                states:[
                    State{
                        name: "moving"
                        when: (azul.Drag.active && verde.Drag.active===false && rojo.Drag.active===false&& naranja.Drag.active===false)
                        ParentChange{
                            target: azul
                            parent: screenCanvasUI

                        }
                        AnchorChanges{
                            target:azul
                            anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined
                            anchors.verticalCenter: undefined
                            anchors.left: undefined
                            anchors.right: undefined
                            anchors.bottom: undefined
                            anchors.top: undefined
                        }
                        PropertyChanges {
                            target: azul
                            width: 200
                            height:200
                            anchors.left: undefined
                            anchors.top: undefined
                        }
                    },
                    State{
                        name: "dropping"
                        when: (toIndex!== -1  && azul.Drag.active===false && verde.Drag.active===false && rojo.Drag.active===false&& naranja.Drag.active===false )
                        ParentChange{
                            target: azul
                            parent:returnFather(posiciones.indexOf("azul"))//{contenedores[toIndex]}

                        }
                        PropertyChanges {
                            target: azul
                            width: parent.width
                            height:parent.height
                            anchors.left: parent.left
                            anchors.top: parent.top

                        }
                    }

                ]
                Item{
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    width: 20
                    height: 20
                    Frame{
                        anchors.fill:parent
                    }
                    MouseArea{
                        id:azulMouseArea
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        drag.target: azul
                        drag.onActiveChanged: {
                            if (azulMouseArea.drag.active)
                            {
                                toIndex=-1

                                fromIndex=posiciones.indexOf("azul");
                                rojo.update=false
                                azul.update=false
                                verde.update=false
                                naranja.update=false
                            }
                            else{

                                var temp= posiciones[fromIndex];
                                posiciones[fromIndex]=posiciones[toIndex]
                                posiciones[toIndex]=temp;
                                azul.Drag.drop();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    //}
    Rectangle{
        id: vtk3dSceneHolder
        width: parent.width*2/3
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        DropArea{
            id: vtk3dDropArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            onEntered: {
                console.log("entrando en area 3D")
                toIndex=3
            }
            onExited: {
                console.log("saliendo de area 3D")

                toIndex=-1
            }

        }
        Rectangle{
            id:naranja
            color: "orange"
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            property bool update:false
            Drag.active: naranjaMouseArea.drag.active
            Drag.hotSpot.x: naranja.width/2
            Drag.hotSpot.y: naranja.height/2
            states:[
                State{
                    name:"moving"
                    when: (naranja.Drag.active && rojo.Drag.active===false && verde.Drag.active===false && azul.Drag.active===false)
                    ParentChange{
                        target: naranja
                        parent: screenCanvasUI
                    }
                    AnchorChanges{
                        target:naranja
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined
                        anchors.verticalCenter: undefined
                        anchors.left: undefined
                        anchors.right: undefined
                        anchors.bottom: undefined
                        anchors.top: undefined
                    }
                    PropertyChanges {
                        target: naranja
                        width: 200
                        height:200
                        anchors.left: undefined
                        anchors.top: undefined
                    }
                },
                State{
                    name: "dropping"
                    when: (toIndex!=-1 && naranja.Drag.active===false && rojo.Drag.active===false && verde.Drag.active===false && azul.Drag.active===false)
                    ParentChange{
                        target:naranja
                        parent: returnFather(posiciones.indexOf("naranja"))//{contenedores[fromIndex] }

                    }
                    PropertyChanges {
                        target: naranja
                        width: parent.width
                        height:parent.height
                        anchors.left: parent.left
                        anchors.top: parent.top
                        update:false
                    }
                }
            ]
            Item{
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.top: parent.top
                width: 20
                height: 20
                Frame{
                    anchors.fill:parent
                }
                MouseArea{
                    id:naranjaMouseArea
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    drag.target: naranja
                    drag.onActiveChanged: {
                        if (naranjaMouseArea.drag.active)
                        {
                            toIndex=-1
                            fromIndex=posiciones.indexOf("naranja");

                        }
                        else{
                            var temp= posiciones[fromIndex];
                            posiciones[fromIndex]=posiciones[toIndex]
                            posiciones[toIndex]=temp;
                            naranja.Drag.drop();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

As I said, the first time y drag something it works, but after that not anymore and i get this error:

```
qrc:/main.qml:388:13: QML Rectangle: Cannot anchor to a null item.
qrc:/main.qml:388:13: QML Rectangle: Cannot anchor to a null item.
qrc:/main.qml:248:13: QML Rectangle: Cannot anchor to a null item.
qrc:/main.qml:248:13: QML Rectangle: Cannot anchor to a null item.
qrc:/main.qml:85:13: QML Rectangle: Cannot anchor to a null item.
qrc:/main.qml:85:13: QML Rectangle: Cannot anchor to a null item.
```

Comment: is that possible to minimize the code? Can you post only relevant code that describes the issue?

Comment: I could delete two of the rectangles, but all the code is intended to solve the problem.  So I don't really see how could I simplify it.  Anyway the four rectangles are exactly the same so is basically repeated code (I know,, it's ugly but is just a proof of concept.

Comment: Create a minimal working example that reproduce the issue, in general, not in your specific case.

Comment: No need we are dealing with a poorly designed layout system. If you will take take my advice: Rectangle requires you specify both width and height or specify an anchors that achieves that. Also you can only do ```Layout.minheight``` if the Rectangle is in a layout say ```RowLayout```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using flow to reimplement all the split view and using a model to move objects around.